# Like search is case sensitive?

Tags: mysql, select, innodb, sql-like, case-sensitive

I have a query like this, executed on a table where there are a couple keywords comma seperated in the field `keywords` with a leading and trailing comma:

```
SELECT media_id, filename FROM media WHERE keywords LIKE '%,house,%'
```

However, it won't find anything (there are a couple thousand records in that table, quite a bunch of which have the keyword `"House"`). Even searching for `'%,House,%'` does find nothing.

What works is doing the like search in all caps:

```
SELECT media_id, filename FROM media WHERE keywords LIKE '%,HOUSE,%'
```

Now it will also find keywords like `House`.

Collation of the table and the `keywords` column is `latin1_german1_ci`.

Where does this behaviour come from?
How do I get the usual completely case-insensitive behaviour?

Comment: What is the collation for the keywords field ?

Comment: Please show the "CREATE TABLE" output for this table.

Comment: @Vatev Collation of table and column is `latin1_german1_ci`.

Comment: for comma separated value you can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extremely stupid and unsolvable problem.

I expanded keywords like `or` or `and` to actual query logic even if they were within a word in the preprocessing script, so searching for `handsome` would be expanded to `h && some`.

I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

When case sensitivity comes into play I will often `LOWER(keywords) like ('%house%')`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the collation of the column OR you can cast it like this:

SELECT media_id, filename FROM media WHERE keywords LIKE '%,house,%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci

Comment: To my understanding `_ci` collations are *c*ase *i*nsensitive and `latin1_german1_ci` is one of them. Are they not?